# Domain wall and kink solutions from solitions equations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, solitons

A general solition equation can be obtaion from scalar field theory $$\varphi(x) = v\tanh\Bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}m(x - x_0)\Bigr),\tag{92.6}$$
where $x_0$ is a constant of integration when we drived this solution from Lagrangian.

**Comparing to the sine-Gordon theory [with this article](http://pauli.uni-muenster.de/tp/fileadmin/lehre/NumMethoden/WS0910/ScriptPDE/SineGordon.pdf) , can we convert our equation to the sine-Gordon equation?**

Because this equation represented for 2 dimensions (1 space dimension and 1 time dimension) then how will I get Kink solutions and domain wall equation from the above equation. 
Any elaboration would be helpful for me.
This is a continuing post of [Solving the soliton equation without energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61019/solving-the-soliton-equation-without-energy).

**ADDITION: 
If I want to visualize the solition equation (92.6) by graph then what would be the best process?**

Comment: Judging from the previous post you are talking about $\phi^4$ theory. In that case no - you *can not* convert the solution from one theory to the other as they are entirely different theories. You *can* however use the same techniques to derive the soliton solution(s) in any 1+1 dimensional scalar field theory.

Comment: Second part: why don't you just plot it like any other function?

Comment: Ohh got it, which theory is most acceptable? I mean, in future I will deal with higher dimensions but sine-Gordon equation is limited into 2 dimension.
So, (92.6) will be better for dimension analysis?

Comment: "which theory is most acceptable?" Neither, or both. Which is to say that it depends on what you are trying to achieve. At a classical level both theories generalise to higher dimensions and the kinks become domain walls. Though sine-Gordon theory is only renormalisable in two dimensions, I believe. $\phi^4$ is renormalisable in four dimensions.

Comment: If I want to visualize the solition equation,  then how will I do it?